# How to get the same reference from an exported member no matter where it was imported from

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have found out that, the second module is using the first module that is published to npm, and the third module is using a local version. So is this technique a bad idea, so I should test for individual elements of the array?

I have a module that exports an array, I want to export this array so I can test for equality with `===`, rather than individual elements.

```
// modulea/index.js

export a = [1, 2];
```

I have another module that uses the first module:

```
// moduleb/index.js
import { a } from 'modulea';

export function sameA(_a) {
  return _a === a;
}
```

I have a third module that uses the first two modules:

```
// modulec/index.js
import { a } from 'modulea';
import { sameA } from 'moduleb';

// I expect this to return true.
sameA(a); // false
```

I want to get the same array no matter where I import the module from. Why is this not working, what should I do instead?

Comment: It returned true for me, seems like something else went wrong

Comment: did you make three npm modules and linked them together?

Comment: Yeah, I have used `npm link` to simulate node_modules for there three modules

Comment: I had no problems until I changed something, now I am getting this. Could it be related to publishing these modules to npm.

Comment: Idk, I've never faced such a issue

Answer (score -1):

false will be returned anyway, when comparing arrays, try comparing numbers instead of arrays
[image: img]